# How to move shared mailbox emails to a folder at the same level as the inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have Outlook code which checks specific subject email in shared mailbox (Inbox) and records the email body data in Excel (yet to add code) and should move the email to MIAL folder.

I get an error while moving emails to MIAL folder.

> "Variable not defined"

Folder (MIAL) was created manually. When I code to move emails to  default folder like "Drafts" or "Sent Folder" its working.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Set Recip = olNs.CreateRecipient("Import-BOM@email.com") 'update email

    Dim SharedInbox As Outlook.Folder
        
    Set SharedInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, _
                                         olFolderInbox) 'Inbox
                                         
    Dim Movefolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set Movefolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, _
                                         olFolderMIAL) 'Folder
                                         
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
       
    For Each Item In SharedInbox.Items
        'If (Item.subject = "TSP") Then
            Debug.Print Item.subject
            Item.Move Movefolder
        'End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Compile error: Variable not defined]
[image: Outlook Shared mailbox Screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are specific default folders that can be described in a similar manner to olFolderInbox to be used as shortcuts.

Manually created folders are referenced the long way.

One way to reference a folder at the same level as an inbox is to navigate the folder tree from that inbox to the mailbox then back down again.

```
Set Movefolder = SharedInbox.Parent.Folders("MIAL")
```

Comment: Above code reading the MIAL folder email details,  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*Move Folder should be*

> ```
> Dim Movefolder As Outlook.folder
> Set Movefolder = SharedInbox.Folders("MIAL")
> ```

Comment: I tried using above code, however getting "Run-time error '-2147221233(80044010f)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found."